# Algorithm for fast split of big files

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was studying a slow algorithm about splitting big text file (real task > 20GB but you can assume 1GB) into smaller files by a header `fafafafa` and found the following algorithm expressed as a pseudocode

You can create binary test data 1GB by the following command, discussed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/193166/15504)

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=sample.bin bs=64M count=16
```

## Current

```
i=1;
matchCount=0;
while not end of file
    read.file
    while matchCount < i 
        match(header "fafafafa", file)
        match(2nd header "fafafafa", file)
        matchCount++; 
    end;
    store everything between two headers into a new file called rd$i.txt
    i++; 
end;
```

Comments

- reading file from the start each time again and again in each iteration

Which others things make this algorithm slow?

## My proposal

```
i=1;
read.file
eventOn = 0; 
while line in linesInFile
    if not match header AND eventOn=0
        stop; # go to next line
    end;
    if match(header "fafafafa" in line)
        negate eventOn; # from 1 to 0; from 0 to 1.
        if newFile is not empty
            store.newFile as rd$i.txt
            newFile = ""; 
            i++;
            stop; # go to next line
        end;
    end; 

    if eventOn=1 
        newFile += line;
    end;
end;
```

Comments

- this should not read from the beginning of the file again and again
- I am not sure if the datastructure of the newFile is sufficient here with `addition` and `delete`; stack could be a nice one; since I need only split the file by headers and fast

Which datastructure is good for fast such a split?

How can you think about the algorithm for a fast splitting of a big file?

Comment: The task description: `splitting 2GB file into smaller files by a header fafafafa` is not clear (to me at least). Can you please clarify?

Comment: And also, it seems like the *Current* algorithm is INTENTIONALLY slow. Is that the case?

Comment: @Amit No. It is a part of an industrial process which is slowing down the production speed many days. I added comment about the big file. 2GB is just a simplification. The real case more than > 20 GB, but here just a simplification of the problem.

Comment: To clarify: You want to split a TEXT file, where the delimiter is a constant string ("fafafa.."), into multiple smaller text files?

Comment: @amit Yes, you can assume the file to be TEXT. It is converted from binary to hex/octave file which you can assume to be text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single scan, keep everything in a buffer till delimiter is found, then write to a new file:

```
f=1
temp= empty string
i=0
delimiter= "fafafafa"
while not eof
   b=readbyte
   if b == delimiter[i]
      if ++i == delimiter length
          truncate delimiter from end of temp
          write temp to rd$f.txt
          f++
          i=0
          temp = delimiter
   else
      i=0

   temp += b

write temp to rd$f.txt
```

Comment: I added data example in the body for testing.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what is it that you're expecting, or what test data you're talking about. Isn't this answer what you wanted?

Comment: I will test your code systematically soon with the test data above added. I do not know yet if this is yet sufficient. I will let you know when I have done some tests.

Comment: In an actual implementation, though, you're going to want to read the data by blocks (whatever blocks are appropriate to the file type) and scan for the delimiter. Then you'll also have to handle the case of the delimiter spanning blocks.

Comment: @beaker - You're right, but that's implementation detail that should be encapsulated, at the app, library or platform level

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about your problem.
You dont want to read the file from beginning again and again.
I would read the file one time and remember the positions of the headers to split "fafafafa". Pointers will do the job. Then you got your big file and a very little array of pointers to the specific headers.

Hope this helps a little